# What is the radius of convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{z^{2n}}{16^{n+1}}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the radius of convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{z^{2n}}{16^{n+1}}}$  in $\mathbb{C}$?

I transformed the series into $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(\frac{z^2}{16})}^{n}*\frac{1}{16}$ so the radius would be  $ |\frac{z^2}{16}| <\frac{1}{\limsup({\frac{1}{16}})^{1/n}}= 1$, that is I would have to find $|z|<r$ from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|z|^2<4^2\Longrightarrow |z|<4$$

Answer (score 0):

The radius of convergence is $4$ because $|z^2/16|\lt1\iff|z|\lt4$.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Hadamard,  we get $r=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \dfrac1{\sqrt[2n]{\dfrac1{16^{n+1}}}}=\dfrac1{\dfrac14}=4$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{z^{2n}}{16^{n+1}}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{z^{2n}}{16^{n}}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{z^{2n}}{4^{2n}}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(\frac{z}{4})^{2n}}$$
$|\frac{z}{4}|<1$